# python: mutating the copy of a list changes the original?

Tags: python, list

So until now, I was under the assumption that if you have, for example:

```
L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = L1
L2.append(5)
```

Both L and L2 would be affected by the append code.

However, when you assign L2 to be a copy of a list, for example:

```
L = [1,2,3]
L2 = L[:]
L2.append(5)
```

only L2 would be affected, and L still refers to [1,2,3]

but I now run into this:

```
x = [1, 2]
L1 = [x, [8, 9]]
L2 = L1[:]
L2[0][1] = 999

>>>print(L1)
[[1,999],[8,9]]
>>>print(L2)
[[1,999],[8,9]]
```

Why was it that in this case, both lists changed?

Answer (score 5):

Slicing is a shallow copy. A copy created by slicing will contain new references to the old elements of the original list; if the original list contained mutable objects such as more lists, the copy will contain references to those same lists. You can use `copy.deepcopy` to try to get around this, or loop through your original list and slice-copy the elements into a new list. Be careful with `copy.deepcopy`, though; there's often some depth at which you want to stop making copies and keep the original elements.