# Why is my variable updating outside the loop

Tags: python

Here is my code, my desired outcome is using `x_temp` to track vector `x` , and terminate the loop when `x` stops mutating.

```
x = [1,0,0,0]
W = [[-7,8,-10,-6],[8,-7,12,10],[-10,12,-7,-10],[-6,10,-10,-4]]
for k in range(1000):
    x_temp = x
    for i in range(4):
        weighted_sum = 0
        print("temp: ",x_temp)
        print("k:",k)
        for j in range(4):
            weighted_sum = W[j][i]*x[j] + weighted_sum
        if weighted_sum < 0:
            x[i] = 0
        else:
            x[i] = 1
    if x == x_temp:
        break
```

However, the outputs shows that `x_temp` is mutating as `x` does. I understand I might have set `x_temp` always equal to `x`. But what is the right way to do this?

This question is the same as:
[python: mutating the copy of a list changes the original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483973/python-mutating-the-copy-of-a-list-changes-the-original)

Comment: because the list is mutable in python
here a reference to the actual list is in x and is updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do: `x_temp = x.copy()`. This is because, the variables `x_temp` and `x` are pointing to the same ram address (same list), not copies. `x.copy()` makes a completely different copy.

You can see this with the [`id(`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function in python.

```py
x = [1,2]
y = x
print(id(x) == id(y)) # This will output True

x1 = [1,2]
y1 = x1.copy()
print(id(x1) == id(y1)) # This will output False
```

The [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function outputs the memory address in base 10, use the [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) function if you want to see it in hex.